# AspectJ and Map<String,Object> Array

Tags: aspectj, ajdt

I am using AJDT 2.2.4 which is build on AspectJ 1.81.

Consider this simple aspect:

```java
@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(logMe)")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, LogMe logMe) {
        System.out.println("Before the method");
    }
}
```

It print some text before LogMe annotation which is :

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogMe {}
```

Now, I apply this annotation to some method as:

```java
public class DummyClass {
   @LogMe
    public void doSomething() {
        SampleUtil sampleUtil = new SampleUtil();
        //pass null for simplicity !
        sampleUtil.sampleMethod(null);
        System.out.println("Do Something");
    }
}
```

The SampleUtil is

```java
public class SampleUtil {    
    public void sampleMethod(
        Map<String, Object>[] mapArray){
    }
}
```

I get this warning:

```
can not resolve this member: 
void foo.SampleUtil.sampleMethod(java.util.Map[]) [Xlint:unresolvableMember]
```

If I change the `sampleMethod` parameter to something else like `Map<String, Object> aMap` the error will go.

Why do I get this warning ?!

Comment: FYI: You cannot name the advice method `before`. This is a reserved keyword in AspectJ, Eclipse will show a strange error message. I will edit your question and rename it to `beforeAdvice`. I will also simplify the aspect code a bit, still keeping the problem reproduceable.

Answer (score 0):

That warning means that it can't find `foo.SampleUtil` on the inpath. The inpath is similar to the classpath, and is used to determine what the aspects weave against.

I am guessing that `foo.SampleUtil` is in another project and this means that you need to explicitly add the project to your inpath.

Since you are using AJDT inside of Eclipse, you can go to the aspect project's properties page and select the AspectJ build path tab. Choose Inpath and add the other project.

Comment: the files are in the same project. Does AJDT provides any log file, maybe I can review and post it here to help. Also as I mentioned when I change **java.util.Map[]** to **java.util.Map** the warning is resolved.

Comment: That actually looks like a compiler bug.  It seems like the code runs as expected, but the warning is being spit out. Can you convert your aspect to a code style aspect? ie- remove the annotations and use `aspect` instead of `class`. In general code style aspectj works better. I tried that out myself and no longer see the bug.  Also, if you have time, I'd suggest raising a bug on the aspectj bugzilla: http://bugs.eclipse.org.

Comment: FYI, I have reproduced the problem and created a [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456357).

Comment: I am looking at the ticket but it had a pointer to here so I wanted to comment. Using `@annotation(Foo)` as your only pointcut element is usually a sign of an anti-pattern. There are many kinds of join point that may have the annotation and you probably don't mean all of them, what you probably mean is execution of a method with the annotation, i.e. `execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Foo)`. Without that, for an annotated method you'll be intercepting calls to the method *and* the execution of that method - which isn't usually what you want. Adding execution() would also fix the warning here...